# How to find a triangle vertices given a barycenter and a normal

Tags: vectors, triangles, barycentric-coordinates

So, I'd need to retrieve the vertices of a triangle, given a point (let's assume being the barycenter) and a normal on that point.

This is needed because then I have to find all the intersection between the triangle and a bunch of rays, and then retrieve an image (or sort of) in order to determine a couple of points out of it that cover the shape evenly. It's graphic related.

I thought at begin to find the vertices in what is called `Model Space` and then apply some transformations (rotation + translation) on the points via matrices.

Essentially:

- barycenter at the origin
- normal `(0, -1, 0)`
- vertices:
- `(0, 0, 1)`
- `(cos(-30°), 0, sin(-30°))`
- `(cos(210°), 0, sin(210°))`

But I have the feeling I'm overdoing it... isn't there a simpler method?

Comment: If all you have is the barycenter and a normal, then you don’t have enough information to reconstruct the triangle. There are an infinite number of them with the same barycenter and in the same plane.

Comment: Right, then let's suppose I'd like to calculate the triangle that if the barycenter is at the origin and the normal is (0, -1, 0), it'd would lie on the xz plane with the upper angle on the positive z axes